# Interpreting high deviance in logistic regression ANOVA output

Tags: logistic, deviance

I'm performing logistic regression. I notice when I introduce one of my variables 'admissions_R,' which is a continuous count of the number of admissions, that the deviance is quite high. However, I'm uncertain as to how to interpret that, and what it means. I'm concerned because my DV is readmissions, so I'm wondering if its flagging a violation?

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to model the proportion of admissions that are readmissions? Ie, do you have admissions on both sides of the = sign?

Comment: I'm trying to model readmits vs non-readmits. So just binary.

Comment: Is admissions the sum of readmits + non-readmits?

Comment: Yes, it would be. Admissions is the total number of times a person was admitted. Some of those may have been a readmit (a repeat visit in the last 30 days), and some of those may have been just a regular admission.

Comment: So then you seem to have the total on both sides of the = sign. It is implied on the LHS, & explicitly listed on the RHS.